# how to add line break after every 5 number?

Tags: python, while-loop

please tell me how can I add line break after every 5 numbers

```
i = 1
while i < 30:
  print(i, end = ' ')
  i += 1
```

Comment: One method: use two nested loops.

Comment: `if i % 5 == 4: …`

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
i = 1
while i < 30:
    print(i, end = '\n' if i % 5 == 0 else " ")
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Should post an example for clarity, this should do it

```
for i in range(1, 30):
  print(i, end=' ')
  if not i % 5:
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Now it only prints every 5th number.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the modulo operator `%` with an `if`-block to check if `i` is a multiple of 5:

```
i = 1
while i < 30:
    print(i, end=' ')
    if i % 5 == 0:
        print()
    i += 1
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 6 7 8 9 10
> 11 12 13 14 15
> 16 17 18 19 20
> 21 22 23 24 25
> 26 27 28 29
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the Modulo funktion, which is done with % in python.

```py
i=1
while i<30:
  print(i, end=' ')
  if i%5 == 0:
    print()
  i += 1
```

the Modulo funktion returns the remainder of the division i/5, which is 0 for 0,5,10 and so on, so every 5 steps.

print('\n') prints a newline

Comment: `print('\n')` prints 2 newlines, and your answer is just otherwise identical to mine and @DeveshKumarSingh answers while adding nothing new.